# Wireless AP on different routers

Tags: wifi, access-point, wireless-bridge

I have a Linksys WAG320N Wireless N router and a Belkin Wireless N router. The Linksys is acting as a modem and DHCP server, and I want to set up the Belkin as an AP. Is there any reason this shouldn't be possible? Am I right in thinking it's a case of connecting the two routers via ethernet and setting up the Belkin as an AP only and giving it a static IP? Do I need to set up the Belkin with the same wireless settings or is there a way to mirror them automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set the Belkin to act as an access point - it's important to disable the DHCP server on the belkin because if there are 2 DHCP servers operating on the same network, you will have conflicts. also important to set the belkin ap with an ip that is in the range of the other router/modem and configure the linksys to reserve an IP for the belkin - this can be done by going to DHCP reservations and adding the MAC address of the belkin. In this way you can control all the IP pool on the network from the DHCP server on the Linksys

Answer (score 1):

I'll just trot out the line from the FaQ: `Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity. If your question is not about <snip> Networking outside the professional workplace then you're in the right place.` So, if this is a home network please say so where it can be migrated to SuperUser when home networking topics are more suited. If this is a *workplace* network I'd think about something a bit more robost than SOHO routers and basic equpiment (budget pending, naturally).

---

Saying that, what you want to do should be fine. The Linksys router, acting as the DHCP server and gateway could be on 192.168.1.1, and then the Belkin could be set on a static IP of 192.168.1.2 (bearning in mind you'll have to change the DHCP server to start handing out addresses from 1.3 rather than 1.2 to avoid problems. Typically, when two wireless networks with the same SSID are in range it should act as a fail-over <sup>(or so I understand it anyway)</sup> but I don't know if something so basic would support "roaming" access, that is, automatically switch between the strongest signals rather than loose access.

The best way, really, is back up the configuration of your hardware, and give it a go.